# Why does this simple RSpec string equality spec fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Given this class:

```
class First
  def to_s ; "Hello World" ; end
end
```

and this spec:

```
require 'first'

describe First do
  describe "#to_s" do
    it { should == "Hello World" }
  end
end
```

I get:

```
Failures:

  1) First#to_s 
     Failure/Error: it { should == "Hello World" }
       expected: "Hello World"
            got: Hello World (using ==)
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -"Hello World"
       +Hello World
     # ./spec/first_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But I would expect this to pass. My questions are:

- How would a passing spec look like?
- Why is this spec not passing, specifically?

Comment: About the rails tags: I didn't put them there, because it is actually not a Rails-specific topic. But I won't remove them either, now that they are there, because of the people interested in the topic probably 80% are Rails devs anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your outer `describe` block:

```
describe First do
```

sets the subject of the inner examples [to be an instance of](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-8/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject) `First`. That is, all of the `it`s you're describing will be a `First` object. The text `#to_s` example doesn't instruct rspec to call `to_s` on the object.

Since `First.new` is not equal to `"Hello World"` the spec fails.

However, since rspec does call `to_s` on the object to output it in the failure description, "Hello World" does appear there. You could try the following to ensure that the string conversion is being tested:

```
its(:to_s) { should == "Hello World" }
```

Comment: Thank you @Gareth and @apneadiving! Two very good answers, though I prefer this one. In summary: **Q1, "How...?"** -- The passing spec that I intended uses `its` (see answer's example) and I can get rid of the inner `describe` level. **Q2, "Why...?"** -- I thought using `describe "#blah"` would set the subject, but that is not the case. Instead, the subject is still `First.new`.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used `#method_name` to get the result evaluated automatically. I prefer verbosity to be sure of what I'm doing.

Generally, I pick one from these:

```
describe First do
  specify { First.new.to_s.should == "Hello World" }
end
```

Or:

```
describe First do
  describe "#to_s" do
    subject { First.new.to_s }
    it { should == "Hello World" }
  end
end
```

Or:

```
describe First do
  describe "#to_s" do
    let(:result) { First.new.to_s }
    specify { result.should == "Hello World" }
  end
end
```